# Reading output from checking syntax thru 'php -l' using shell_exec

Tags: php

I want to check syntax using `shell_exec('php -l test.php')`;
when I use sth like

```
$rc = shell_exec('php -l test.php');
```

it returns only ***'error parsing test.php'***, but not the error details. How to read these error details?

Thanx in advance

Comment: This is all documented for `shell_exec`, `exec` and the like. I suggest you start reading the documentation of those commands you want to use. That saves you from having to ask. Start here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php

Comment: I solved this problem by using $rc = shell_exec( $cmd." 2>&1" );